# Editing polygon to cut out some points within it so that polygon goes around these points using QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have produced a polygon and need to remove the selected points from the polygon.

However, I want this to result in the orange polygon completely excluding these points so that there is just blank space/the basemap in these locations?

[image]

Comment: You are aware of the fact that points are onedimensional? So you really want to build a difference between points and polygon or rather between pointbuffers and polygon?

Comment: Another option is to build a convex hull around points that are within the polygon, and after applying a difference geoalogorithm.

Comment: @MrXsquared hi many thanks for your comment. Yes aware points are 1D. I suppose pointbuffers Vs polygons would be fine as long as the buffers are very small (each point is a small house). I used the difference tool under the vector tab but this didn't work. Again apologies if dumb question but would appreciate any pointers!

Comment: @Taras thanks Taras that sounds interesting, does sound a bit beyond my ability though :-)

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a (small) buffer around your points to convert them to polygons.
2. Run difference tool using these buffers as input.

---

Another option is to use QGIS expressions with Geometry generator (for visualisation only) or Geometry by expression (to create actual geometries). [See here for details](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814).

Use this expression on the point layer and rename `poly` to the name of your polygon layer and change the value of `40` to adapt the buffer size:

```
difference (
    overlay_within('poly', $geometry)[0],  -- change poly to the name of your polygon layer
    buffer (collect ($geometry), 40)  -- change this value to adapt buffer size
)
```

*The solution using Geometry generator: the red polygon corresponds to the yellow (invisible) one but with small holes cut out where the blue points are:*
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Babel this sounds great, I'll give it a go tomorrow.